# python- Recursion error while trying to create a copy of spark dataframe using the copy module

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a copy of a spark dataframe using the `copy` module of python but I am running into a `RecursionError`. Following is the code I am using

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],['x1','x2'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
| x1| x2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
>>> import copy
>>> df_copy = copy.copy(df)
```

This code results into a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Same is the case when I use `copy.deepcopy` as well.

What is the correct way to create copies of a spark dataframe in python? And why does the current approach result in a recursion error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To (shallow) copy a `DataFrame` you can just assign it to a new variable:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1,2,3] })
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df2 = df
df2 = df2.withColumn('x1', F.col('x1') + 1)

print('df:')
df.show()
print('df2:')
df2.show()
```

Output:

```
df:
+---+
| x1|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+

df2:
+---+
| x1|
+---+
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

As you can see, after copying `df` to `df2` and mutating the copy, our original `DataFrame` `df` remains unchanged.

Comment: I checked with the `is` operator. It returns `False`.

Comment: @ClockSlave The two variables are indeed not the same object, which is what the `is` operator tests. When copied, the `DataFrames` do have the same value though (it is a shallow copy). I don't think it is possible to create a deep copy of a spark `DataFrame`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.